# como subtrair data da coluna com a data do sistema?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma coluna com data `data_novo` e quero saber a quantos dias o produto esta em aberto, tenho que fazer uma conta de subtração entre a "data do sistema" e a data que esta na coluna `data_novo`. E esse resultado vai ser exibido em outra coluna (ex.: dias em aberto). Como posso fazer isso?

Tentei o seguinte:

```
diferença= DATETIME-DAT_ABER
```

Não faço ideia de como fazer. Podem me ajudar por favor?

Comment: `diferenca = getdate() - dat_abert`

Comment: tentei dessa forma e não funcionou.

Comment: Você vai realizar um update? Não entendi isso: `esse resultado vai ser exibido em outra coluna`

Comment: É isto? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/21540

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função DATEDIFF do sql server:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,startDate,endDate) AS 'Duration'  
FROM dbo.Duration;
```

Nesse caso ele calcula a diferença de dias entre duas datas.

Comment: tentei isso, mas não deu certo Maycon: SELECT top 100*
select DATEDIFF(day,startDate,data_abertura) AS 'Duration'  
 FROM [tb_a] WITH (NOLOCK)

Comment: acho que não deu certo porque minha coluna carrega a informação de data da seguinte forma: 2017-08-12 14:32:23.000

Comment: A sua coluna de data_abertura?

Comment: Isso mesmo Maycon.

Comment: Tenta SELECT top 100* select DATEDIFF(day,GetDate(),data_abertura) AS 'Duration' FROM [tb_a] WITH (NOLOCK)

Comment: Bom dia. Deu certo Maycon. muito obrigado. abs